# Cannot call method of a button from a custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, delegates, protocols

I want to call an action from a button which is inside a custom View. The view itself is part of a UIViewController. But when I tapped the view, nothing happens. I do not know where my mistake is, although my code looks like the ones on stackoverflow.

```
protocol StoreDelegate: class {
    func didPressButton(_ sender: UIButton)
}

class Store: UIView {

    weak var delegate:StoreDelegate?

    var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPress(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

   @objc func buttonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didPressButton(sender)
        print("here")
    }

}
```

And this is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, StoreDelegate{

    var testView = Store()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(testView)
    }

    func didPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Neither it prints "Hello" nor "Here". Maybe I have misunderstood the protocol/delegate pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set constraints or a frame to the view

```
testView.frame = ///////
```

It's the base behind receiving actions

Comment: How could I miss that ? It works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement override `sizeToFit` in `Store` class to match your needs:

```
override func sizeToFit() {
    frame.size = button.frame.size
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
testView.sizeToFit()
```

<sub>You may consider using autolayout for better sizing.</sub>